# Modify Spotlight metadata for a file outside Spotlight importer?

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight

I would like to modify a Spotlight metadata attribute of a file within my application (i.e. not in a Spotlight importer) but I can't find any API for doing so. Is it possible? Pointers to the relevant docs would be ideal.

In case it's helpful, here's my use case:

> I want to store a reference to a file
>   system path in a Core Data store.
>   Ideally, I should be able to find the
>   file even if is moved, potentially
>   across mounted volumes. My understanding is that
>   an archived FSRef or AliasRecord will not do the trick because they
>   are not invariant wrt to moves across mounted
>   volumes. So my plan was to store a URL
>   and also to add a UUID (also stored in
>   the data store) to the file's
>   Spotlight metadata so that I could
>   perform a Spotlight query for that
>   UUID if the URL no longer pointed to
>   the file when the app goes back to
>   look for the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research, using Spotlight is not the best solution for the use case. The AliasRecord is a better persistent storage for a file. It automatically tracks moves/renames/etc. You can read more about AliasRecords [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html). Chris Hansen has written an Objective-C wrapper for AliasRecords, `BDAlias`. It's currently available from the [rentzsch.com](http://rentzsch.com/svn/trunk/cocoa/BDAlias/) SVN.